Power Query Getting the percentage distribution for each column in a table, dynamic columns
I'm practically new in Power Query, I did some simple queries in the past, but I'm trying to make a dynamic one to process the data in a table to calculate the percentage distribution of the absolutes and this is what I have so far...
Basically I'm stuck in getting the final step (and the most important one), the division of the recorded value times the total of the column,
My final result should be the percentage distribution and my example data is something like this, my interest on making it dynamic is for always to be able to detect the columns, since this are suppose to be dynamic (always increasing in terms of periods),



Product
Q1 - 2020
Q2 - 2020
Q3 - 2020
Q4 - 2020
Q1 - 2021
Q2 - 2021
Q3 - 2021
Q4 - 2021




P1
1144
2737
3545
3696
4279
4249
4167
4124


P2
157
161
166
163
166
174
163
175


P3
257
388
485
529
553
566
585
598


P4
251
461
587
709
820
848
878
924


P5
262
402
493
465
502
512
507
550


P6
193
220
236
255
256
269
251
253


P7
160
161
171
184
214
236
243
244


P8
177
249
300
384
488
518
558
566


P9
202
226
231
245
246
258
283
275


P10
154
154
154
154
154
157
166
163


P11
155
156
167
166
203
236
251
246


P12
165
163
159
168
174
167
170
177


P13
156
159
157
160
170
161
164
169













P1
33.3%
48.6%
51.7%
50.8%
52.0%
50.9%
49.7%
48.7%


P2
4.6%
2.9%
2.4%
2.2%
2.0%
2.1%
1.9%
2.1%


P3
7.5%
6.9%
7.1%
7.3%
6.7%
6.8%
7.0%
7.1%


P4
7.3%
8.2%
8.6%
9.7%
10.0%
10.2%
10.5%
10.9%


P5
7.6%
7.1%
7.2%
6.4%
6.1%
6.1%
6.0%
6.5%


P6
5.6%
3.9%
3.4%
3.5%
3.1%
3.2%
3.0%
3.0%


P7
4.7%
2.9%
2.5%
2.5%
2.6%
2.8%
2.9%
2.9%


P8
5.2%
4.4%
4.4%
5.3%
5.9%
6.2%
6.7%
6.7%


P9
5.9%
4.0%
3.4%
3.4%
3.0%
3.1%
3.4%
3.2%


P10
4.5%
2.7%
2.2%
2.1%
1.9%
1.9%
2.0%
1.9%


P11
4.5%
2.8%
2.4%
2.3%
2.5%
2.8%
3.0%
2.9%


P12
4.8%
2.9%
2.3%
2.3%
2.1%
2.0%
2.0%
2.1%


P13
4.5%
2.8%
2.3%
2.2%
2.1%
1.9%
2.0%
2.0%



let
        Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Line1_Abs"]}[Content],
        //Organization will always be of type text.  The others will be should be numbers, unless user error
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Product_Regimen", type text}}),
       //function to replace all values in all columns with percentages values
       MultiplyReplace = (DataTable as table, DataTableColumns as list) =>
         let
            Counter = Table.ColumnCount(DataTable),
            ReplaceCol = (DataTableTemp, i) =>
                let
                    colName = DataTableColumns{i},
                    colTotal = List.Sum(Record.FieldValues(_, colName)),
                    //Line not doing the trick
                    ReplaceTable = Table.ReplaceValue(DataTableTemp,each Record.Field(_, colName), each if Record.Field(_, colName) is number then Record.Field(_, colName)/List.Sum(Record.FieldValues(_, colName)) else Record.Field(_, colName),Replacer.ReplaceValue,{colName})
    
                in
                    if i = Counter-1 then ReplaceTable else @ReplaceCol(ReplaceTable, i+1)
         in
            ReplaceCol(DataTable, 0),
        allColumns = Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),
        #"Multiplied Numerics" = MultiplyReplace(#"Changed Type", allColumns)
    
    in
        #"Multiplied Numerics"


You can use this https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/ to convert an excel table into a copiable markdown.

without a data sample posted as text, and a screenshot of your expected results, your question is not useful.

This divides every row by the sum of the column for all columns except those purposely excluded
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Ignore={"Product"},
ChosenNames=List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(Source),Ignore),
ChosenColumns = Table.ToColumns(Table.SelectColumns(Source,ChosenNames)),
Process = Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(Table.SelectColumns(Source,Ignore))&List.Transform(ChosenColumns,(x)=> List.Transform(x, each _/List.Sum(x))),Table.ColumnNames(Source))
in Process   


